# RuntimeError: Event loop is closed - Telegram

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, python-asyncio, telethon

I'm trying to run a telegram client using the async module like in the [documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/telethon/latest/telethon.pdf) on page 15

```
import telethon
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import asyncio

client = TelegramClient(USERNAME, API_ID, API_HASH)

async def main():
    await client.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

When trying to run `await client.start()` I get the following error.

```
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<MTProtoSender._send_loop() running at 
/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telethon/network/mtprotosender.py:347> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<MTProtoSender._recv_loop() running at /home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telethon/network/mtprotosender.py:411> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]>>
Exception ignored in: <coroutine object MTProtoSender._send_loop at 0x7f27c688b468>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telethon/network/mtprotosender.py", line 347, in _send_loop
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telethon/network/mtprotosender.py", line 720, in get
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/queues.py", line 170, in get
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 227, in cancel
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 242, in _schedule_callbacks
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 497, in call_soon
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 506, in _call_soon
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 334, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<UpdateMethods._update_loop() running at /home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telethon/client/updates.py:206> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]>>
```

Is there any way of fixing this without going into the module code or am I doing something wrong with asyncio?

Comment: Try removing or commenting out the lines `loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()` and `asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)`.

Comment: @user4815162342 still gives the exact same error. If i remove ```await client.start()``` and replace it with ```pass``` it runs fine. If I remove ```await``` and just run ```client.start()``` it gives me the error ```connect.py:15: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AuthMethods.start' was never awaited client.start()```

Answer (score 0):

```
api_id = your id
api_hash = ''
bot_token = ''

with TelegramClient('session name', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=bot_token) as client:
     client.send_message('id', message)
```

if you don't use bot and using your account remove the start bot code and also don't need bot token

using the news version of telethon and test both (telethon, telethon.sync)

and if it couldn't help using celery and it doing for you 
I'm using it in my django project and work